# Will a visa be necessary for UK citizens to travel by bus to Paris?

Tags: visas, buses, uk-citizens

We are traveling from London to Paris by bus, booked on a website called flixbus. It says on our booking reference that we need a visa, but as we are both British citizens and are from the UK, and are only traveling for a few days, we didn't think we would need it. We are unsure whether to get a visa to be sure or leave it, as every other thing that we search says we don't need one.

If anyone can help that would be great.

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't say 'you **may** require a visa'? Adding a link to the page and/or adding the paragraph with the exact text would be better.

Answer (score 4):

British citizens do not need a visa for France, or anywhere in the EU/Schengen.
And until the electronic admission scheme actually starts also nothing else apart from a passport less than 10 year old on arrival, with three months left validity.

I guess that the line about visa is for non British/non EU or Schengen passengers who will be responsible to get their own visa if they need them.
Not all visitors need visa but the bus lines will not worry about whom need them, they just warn everybody that it is their responsibility.

Comment: Simply for the benefit of people who may see this in future years: from 2025, it is expected that British citizens will need an ETIAS (electronic visa-waiver) to visit France and/or anywhere else in the Schengen area.

Comment: The passport must also have at least 3 months left on arrival. And it may be worth noting the Bristish citizens have to abide by the 90/180 rule in the Schengen Area. longer stays would require some kind of visa.

Comment: @JackAidley ETIAS has been postponed so many times now I suspect it will be 2030 in the end :-)

Comment: @jcaron the passport must be valid for three months beyond the date of anticipated departure.  If you're planning to stay for a month, it needs to be valid for four months, etc.